# Animations in Compose not working after dependency updates

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose

After updating Compose to be able to use Modifier.blur, I got errors which were resolved after updating other dependencies. But now two animations I use (AnimateDpAsState and AnimatedVisibility) does not work.

I get the following error while building in release mode and it still builds successfully. No errors on debug mode.

```
lifecycle-runtime-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I am pretty sure the problem lies in the gradle files so please take a look.

**module build.grade**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt"
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.app'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    // Compose 
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.0-alpha05"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01"


    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44.2'

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0"
}
```

**project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44.2' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.8.0" apply false
}
```

I updated dependencies highlighted by Android Studio and Compose and was expecting it to work as it was with the new versions. No extra dependencies were added nor was the code modified.

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by the suggestions from: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#usage-of-the-latest-kotlin-stdlib-version-in-transitive-dependencies  Specifically for me it was the `implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0'))` that fixed it